# Calculate number of password combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

An eight-character password consisting of upper- and lowercase letters and at least one numeric digit (0–9):

My working:

Passwords including digits:
62^8

passwords with no digits:
 52^8

Passwords with at least one digit:

(62^8)-(52^8) =
 164 880 377 053 440.

Is this correct?
 I was told it is wrong and the answer given was 62^8 = 2.1834011E+14

Comment: Yes, that's perfect.

Comment: Your computation is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Number of password combinations   =

total number of combinations formed from upper case, lower case and digits 0 to 9  - [number of combinations without any digit + number of combinations     excluding either upper or lower case letters - number of combinations with only upper or only lower case letters]   =

(62^8) - [52^8 + 2.36^8 - 2.26^8]